# How to preserve character case using string.replace()?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, case-sensitive

I am attempting to write a function that will replace all of the vowels in a string with another arbitrary vowel which is selected by an end user. So far, I have been able to write a function that will replace all of the vowels regardless of case, but I would like to be able to preserve the case during `replace()`.

Here is an example of what I am doing right now.

```
var selectedVowel = "a";
var vowels = /[aeiouAEIOU]/gi;

function rep(string){
let newString = string.replace(vowels, selectedVowel);
return newString;
}

rep("FooBar Exe. unIt");
// returns "FaaBar axe. anat"
// Intended output should return "FaaBar Axe. anAt"
```

I have tried using Regular Expressions to modify the search criteria for `replace()` and `selectedVowel`, but I can't figure out how to use the right regex characters to achieve that end.

I have also looked into methods that use `split()` to replace the first letter of a word, but this method seems to be limited to the string's indexes, which are not known at the time of the function call.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) takes a function in place of the substitution string, which is called for each match.

You could write a function that checks each match and replaces it with `selectedVowel` as-is or uppercased, depending on the case of the matched string.

A little trick to check if a character is upper/lowercase is to compare it to the upper/lowercased version of itself, as in `match === match.toUpperCase()`.

```js
var selectedVowel = "a";
var vowels = /[aeiouAEIOU]/gi;

function rep(string){
  return string.replace(vowels, match => {
    if (match === match.toUpperCase()) {
      return selectedVowel.toUpperCase()
    }
    return selectedVowel
  });
}

console.log(rep("FooBar Exe. unIt")) //=> "FaaBar Axa. anAt"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the insight.